# Jquery issue in Firefox and Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a jquery for required validation for different controls in a .net web page. 
the j query works fine in IE but in Google chrome and Firefox it doesn't work.

In this j query i am checking whether the current control is enabled if it is enabled then i check if the input inside is enabled. if both of them are enabled then i check whether, at least one input is selected if it is not selected then i store the value and later on alert it. 
this query works fine in IE but in Firefox and Google chrome it doesn't even check it.

```
 if ($("#<%=chk_ctrl.ClientID%>").is(':enabled')) {
        if ($("#<%=chk_ctrl.ClientID%> input[type='radio']").is(':enabled')) {
          if ($("#<%=chk_ctrl.ClientID%> input[type='radio']:checked").length == 0) {
                      names.push($("#<%=chk_ctrl.ClientID%> input[type='radio']").parent().closest("table").parent().children("h3").text()); +"\n";
                    }
                } 
            }
```

so this works fine with IE it is not working in Chrome and FireFox...any idea

Here is the HTML

I am not sure if HTML is needed but Just in Case. this is a asp.net checkboxlist server  control

```
<table id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_chk_ctrl" class="required" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_chk_ctrl_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$m$g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003$ctl00$chk_ctrl$0" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_chk_ctrl_0">Short-term exposure</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_chk_ctrl_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$m$g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003$ctl00$chk_ctrl$1" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_chk_ctrl_1">Medium-term exposure</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_chk_ctrl_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$m$g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003$ctl00$chk_ctrl$2" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_chk_ctrl_2">Long-term exposure</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post the final HTML, not the server-side code. Also: are there any JavaScript errors in your browser console?

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome and look at Console tab, it often displays errors.

Comment: no errors in FF or Chrome. It works in IE fine

Comment: if i remove the enabled portion, if i don't check whether the control is enabled or disabled then it works. but i need to check if the control is enabled or disabled. this control gets enabled and disabled depending on the value from previous page controls or controls in the same page.

Comment: the answer is this is how it is done \n                              if (!($("#<%=chk_ctrl.ClientID%>").prop('disabled')))

Answer (score 0):

right way instead of using is use prop and check for disabled.

```
     if (!($("#<%=lstExposureValue.ClientID%>").prop('disabled')))
```